# Emulator can't start while Using android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I was trying to set up my Emulator but it doesn't work , what could be the problem . below is the Error am getting.

```
NAND: could not write file C:\Users\HUZY_K~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP2708.tmp, No space left on device
```

Please am stuck .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a way of reducing your `C:` volume. It seems it has little space.

Press `Windows Button + R`, then type in `%temp%` then you delete all those folders inside to free some space.